# How can I use SimpleModal to confirm before going to a URL in a select list?

Tags: jquery, url, select, simplemodal, confirm

I have a form like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="page1.html" class="confirm">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.html" class="confirm">Page 2</option>
    <option value="page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to use SimpleModal to show a confirmation before going to Page 1 or Page 2, but not if Page 3 is selected. The confirmation message should be the same for Page 1 and Page 2. I'm a little confused about how to do the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JavaScript from the [SimpleModal Confirm Demo](http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/downloads/detail?name=simplemodal-demo-confirm-1.4.1.zip) as an example, you could do the following:

```
    // replace 'form' with your form selector
$('form').submit(function (e) {

            // replace 'option:selected' with a more specific selector
    var opt = $('option:selected');

            // if the selected option has a class of confirm, show the dialog
    if (opt.hasClass('confirm')) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // example of calling the confirm function
        // you must use a callback function to perform the "yes" action
        confirm("Continue to the SimpleModal Project page?", function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/';
        });
    }
});
```